# Richfaces 4.3 - Disable resource (JS/CSS) loading

Tags: java, richfaces, web.xml

Is there a way to to prevent loading richfaces resources on 4.3.* version? Old RF version's settings as well as any other relevant settings I found on google don't work:

```
<context-param>  
    <param-name>org.richfaces.resourceOptimization.enabled</param-name>  
    <param-value>true</param-value>  
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadStyleStrategy</param-name>
    <param-value>NONE</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadScriptStrategy</param-name>
    <param-value>NONE</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Why would you not want the JS files? The components won't work without them.

Comment: I have a whole load of custom components, JS libs and styles, which conflict with RS resources. It would be much simpler for me to handpick what I need rather than resolve conflicts.

Comment: Or I may want to use specific version of some library that RF is importing (e.g. jQuery/jQuery UI)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change `<h:head>` for `<head>`, RichFaces won't inject the scripts. You'll have to insert everything else manually, though, so I recommend first loading the page with `<h:head>` and seeing the generated HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Such feature has not been yet implemented in RichFaces 4.x, refer to the ticket: [RF-11514](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-11514).
Also in the ticket's comments a workaround is given to implement own [ResourceMapper](https://github.com/richfaces/richfaces/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/richfaces/resource/mapping/ResourceMapper.java).

To override specific scripts/resources or pick a specific version of a library consider using [resource mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_X/Developer_Guide/en-US/html/chap-Developer_Guide-Advanced_features.html#sect-Developer_Guide-Advanced_features-Resource_optimization) as well.

Comment: Thanks! I've ended up overriding scripts using h:outputScript tag.